# Can we execute our test manually on one device and replay the same tests on multiple devices?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, cross-browser-testing, browserstack, mobile-testing

I want to test a shopping website, a portal where users can view/filter products (clothes, shoes, etc) the actual buying happens somewhere else, it's kind of an aggregator. [The website is UI heavy - Angular]

I want to test this on multiple mobile devices + browser combinations, of course doing it manually on physical devices is not feasible. I have tried the tool called 'CrossBrowserTesting' and I must say it's very slow and will take an eternity for anyone to perform testing.
The second option is BrowserStack, but I am not really sure which product of BrowserStack can be bought. Do we have 'record and replay' kind of a setting with BrowserStack where I perform the manual tests on any one specific device and all those tests can be replayed on another set of devices [under BrowserStack ecosystem] or anything else which can reduce the efforts and increase the coverage [for devices + browsers]

We are also developing the UI automation using Behave + Python and so far we have successfully automated our smoke test suite [Regression is in progress], can we also use the existing selenium scripts with BrowserStack [ I know the answer is YES but this will only cover different browsers and not mobile devices, I guess]

Any inputs here will be really helpful, looking forward to the same

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to have a look at BrowserStack website, they actually answer all of your questions.

However, to point you a bit to the right direction, as of May 2021, BrowserStack offers these products:

[image]

Out of these, you will likely be interested in these 3:

[image]

because they let you test in desktop, tablet, and mobile browsers on various devices and operating systems. A quick look is this screen, you can see there're lots of options:

[image]

**Live** product is with no automation, probably not what you're looking for right now. **Automate** lets you execute various scripts (you can choose [here](https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium), Cypress is also supported). **Percy** is a visual testing tool, it basically takes screenshots of your web app and compares them against some baseline you feed to it.

Now on to you questions:

> Do we have 'record and replay' kind of a setting with BrowserStack

BrowserStack is not a tool that will generate any code, it only runs code that you're provided on devices and in browsers you specified. So if you choose a tool like TestCafe Studio, Cypress Studio, or similar, then you can have record & replay feature, but that's something you prepare locally and only then send it over to BrowserStack to execute that code.

> We are also developing the UI automation using Behave + Python and so far we have successfully automated our smoke test suite [Regression is in progress], can we also use the existing selenium scripts with BrowserStack [ I know the answer is YES but this will only cover different browsers and not mobile devices, I guess]

Mobile browsers and devices typically display a page differently than desktop browsers. What usually happens is some elements are hidden in mobile browsers, or some other elements get used. If you've created a script that is tied to a desktop browser, it might be a problem because some selectors will just fail, therefore your whole script will fail. This of course depends on a particular app (which we'r not familiar here), so there's still a chance everything will work smoothly on all platforms, but I'd guess it won't and you'll have to spend time adjusting your scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. This is surely helpful.